# Navigating the Excel Insert dialog with the keyboard

Tags: ms-office

When presented with the `Insert` dialog:

[image]

I have been unable to find any way to navigate the selections with just the keyboard.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does the tab key not work?

Comment: @JMY1000  no the tab does not work.